# error printing a figure in matlab in specific format

Tags: matlab, printing, plot, subplot

I am trying to print a plot in matlab in .fig format.
I first tried printing using something like print('filename', 'fig') and I got an error that says Multiple inputs that look like file names: 'filename' and 'fig'.
Then I tried print('-f1', 'filename', '-djpeg') and this worked.
I am not sure why I am unable to print to .fig format. I want to print in such way it is more clear for viewing. Please suggest which option should I be using. I am having different subplots

```
 h(1) = subplot(plotCount,1,inputsAxis) %[1 2]
 h(2) = subplot(plotCount,1,errorAxis)  %[3 4]
 h(7) = subplot(plotCount,1,OutputAxis) %5
```

Comment: Use `savefig` to get a `.fig` file and `print` to get an image.

Comment: `fig` is a Matlab file format, not an image format. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, `saveas(fig,filename)`

For PNG;

```
saveas(fig,'MyFig.png');
```

For JPG;

```
saveas(fig,'MyFig.jpg');
```